# Is there a name for a transitive and reflexive but not symmetric relationship?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

How do you call a relationship that is transitive and reflexive but not symmetrical? Not antisymmetrical or asymmetrical or anything - just not symmetrical? Where there exist a and  that a is in a relation with b, but b is not in relation with a and nothing more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called preorder. [See here for more informations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder)